# is there any way to find or remove rar file password without brute force or dictionary attack?

Tags: password-recovery

I have a rar file with password protection. I forgot the password. Is there any way to find or remove rar file password without brute force or dictionary attack ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Otherwise the presence of the password wouldn't matter at all.

Update: ["WinRAR offers you the benefit of industry strength archive encryption using AES (Advanced Encryption Standard) with a key of 256 bits."](http://www.rarlab.com/rar_archiver.htm) And, according to some calculations, using a considerably impossible amount of modern GPUs (one billion), ["it would take ~6.7e40 times longer than the age of the universe to exhaust half of the keyspace of a AES-256 key."](https://www.reddit.com/r/theydidthemath/comments/1x50xl/time_and_energy_required_to_bruteforce_a_aes256/)

Comment: Thanks drookie. is it possible to do it by some hex editor or debugger or by reverse engineering ?

Comment: Wasn't the answer telling clearly enough that it is not possible?